# Ember.js (Emberscript) render cause "Could not find "myModal" template or view" error

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

like the title said,

here is my `route` code:

```
class Route extends Em.Route
  actions:
    openModal: (modalName)->
      return @render modalName,
        into: 'template',
        outlet: 'modal'

`export default Route`
```

My main template/`template.hbs` (where I call for the modal):

```
<main class="platform">
  <div style="padding: 20px; text-align: center" class="row">      
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <button {{action 'openModal' 'myModal'}} class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</main>
{{outlet modal}}
```

My `myModal.hbs` file content (in case it is needed):

```
<div><h1>A Modal</h1></div>
```

My folder structure:

```
- app
    - projects
        - route.js

        - myModal.hbs
        - template.hbs
```

They are causing `Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Could not find "myModal" template or view.` error when I click the button from the template.

My question is, where is actually I should put the `myModal` template file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have some kind of autoload templates? Try creating dir `my` inside `template` with `modal.hbs` inside.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My problem was generating the modal as a component instead of a template. Moving the hbs out of the components folder resolved the issue.
Also for ember conventions use hyphen (my-modal) instead of camel case (myModal).